# Grouping lines with Parsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, parsec, megaparsec

I have a line-based text format I want to parse with `Parsec`†. A line either starts with a pound sign and specifies a key value pair separated by a colon or is a URL that is described by the previous tags.

Here's a short example:

```
#foo:bar
#faz:baz
https://example.com
#foo:beep
https://example.net
```

For simplicity's sake, I'm going to store everything as `String`. A Tag is a `type Tag = (String, String)`, for example `("foo", "bar")`. Ultimately, I'd like to group these as `([Tag], URL)`.

However, I struggle figuring out how to parse either [one or more tags] or [one URL].

My current approach looks like this:

```
import qualified System.Environment   as Env
import qualified Text.Megaparsec      as M
import qualified Text.Megaparsec.Text as M

type Tag = (String, String)

data Segment = Tags [Tag] | URL String
  deriving (Eq, Show)

tagP :: M.Parser Tag
tagP = M.char '#' *> ((,) <$> M.someTill M.printChar (M.char ':') <*> M.someTill M.printChar M.eol) M.<?> "Tag starting with #"

urlP :: M.Parser String
urlP = M.someTill M.printChar M.eol M.<?> "Some URL"

parser :: M.Parser Segment
parser = (Tags <$> M.many tagP) M.<|> (URL <$> urlP)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  fname <- head <$> Env.getArgs
  res <- M.parseFromFile (parser <* M.eof) fname
  print res
```

If I try to run this on the above sample, I get a parsing error like this:

```
3:1:
unexpected 'h'
expecting Tag starting with # or end of input
```

Clearly my use of `many` in combination with `<|>` is incorrect. Since the tag parser won't consume any input from the URL parser it cannot be related to backtracking. How do I need to change this to get to the desired result?

The full example is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/passy/playground/tree/master/haskell/parsing).

---

† I'm actually using MegaParsec here for better error messages but I think the problem is quite generic and not about any particular implementation of parser combinators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@cocreature](https://twitter.com/cocreature) answered this for me [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/cocreature/status/744147207562092544).

As [leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) pointed out here, there are two separate mistakes in my code:

1. The parser itself misuses `<|>` while it should just sequentially parse the lines and skip to the next parser if it doesn't consume any input.
2. The invocation (`parseFromFile`) only applies the `parser` function a single time and would fail as soon as it would get to the second block.

We can fix the parser and introduce grouping in one go:

```
parser :: M.Parser ([Tag], String)
parser = liftA2 (,) (M.many tagP) urlP
```

Afterwards, we just need to apply the change suggested by leftaroundabout:

```
...
res <- M.parseFromFile (M.many parser <* M.eof) fname
```

Running this leads to the desired result:

```
[([("foo","bar"),("faz","baz")],"https://example.com"),([("foo","beep")],"https://example.net")]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing works quite fine, only, at the moment you only parse a single segment (i.e., either *only tags* or *only a URL*), but that doesn't consume the whole input. It's `eof` that's causing the error.

Simply use one more `many` or `some`, to allow for multiple segments:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
  fname <- head <$> Env.getArgs
  res <- M.parseFromFile (many parser <* M.eof) fname
  print res
```

Comment: That's an additional mistake I made in the example. It doesn't even get to that point, though, because it already fails on line 3. I got the answer on Twitter for the mistake in the parser itself, which I'll add here in a minute. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, actually, your approach with `<|>` _does_ work too, if you combine it with `many` segments! It's just a bit oblique, because `[Segment]` doesn't really express the intent of always alternating between a tag- and a URL segment.